# Accessing nested JSON object with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, console, console.log

I am trying to access a nested JSON object and display it within the console.

Here is my JSON

```js
 {
  "currentUser": {
    "image": { 
      "png": "./images/avatars/image-juliusomo.png",
      "webp": "./images/avatars/image-juliusomo.webp"
    },
    "username": "juliusomo"
  },
  "comments": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "content": "Impressive! Though it seems the drag feature could be improved. But overall it looks incredible. You've nailed the design and the responsiveness at various breakpoints works really well.",
      "createdAt": "1 month ago",
      "score": 12,
      "user": {
        "image": { 
          "png": "./images/avatars/image-amyrobson.png",
          "webp": "./images/avatars/image-amyrobson.webp"
        },
        "username": "amyrobson"
      },
      "replies": []
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "content": "Woah, your project looks awesome! How long have you been coding for? I'm still new, but think I want to dive into React as well soon. Perhaps you can give me an insight on where I can learn React? Thanks!",
      "createdAt": "2 weeks ago",
      "score": 5,
      "user": {
        "image": { 
          "png": "./images/avatars/image-maxblagun.png",
          "webp": "./images/avatars/image-maxblagun.webp"
        },
        "username": "maxblagun"
      },
      "replies": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "content": "If you're still new, I'd recommend focusing on the fundamentals of HTML, CSS, and JS before considering React. It's very tempting to jump ahead but lay a solid foundation first.",
          "createdAt": "1 week ago",
          "score": 4,
          "replyingTo": "maxblagun",
          "user": {
            "image": { 
              "png": "./images/avatars/image-ramsesmiron.png",
              "webp": "./images/avatars/image-ramsesmiron.webp"
            },
            "username": "ramsesmiron"
          }
        },
        ]
        }
        }
```

I am trying to access the reply by doing    console.log(data.comments.replies); When i do this I get the following error in the console.

> TypeError: comments.replies is undefined

Here is my code

```js
fetch('./data.json', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
    },
})
    .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data.comments.replies);
        
    })
     .catch((error) => {
         console.log(error);
     });
```

I would like to loop over the array in order to display the information in html. I am un clear how to do this

Comment: `comments` is an array, it doesn't have `replies` property

Comment: what is the best to access it? I'm new to this

Comment: I couldn't find this anywhere online

Comment: You didn't search long enough

Comment: _"...access a nested JSON object..."_ - [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: funny how i have been search for hours and haven't found the answer and honest I'm trying to loop over the information to display it in html

Answer (score 1):

Use index

```
data.comments[index].replies
```

Example:

```
data.comments[1].replies
```

```js
const data = {
  "currentUser": {
    "image": {
      "png": "./images/avatars/image-juliusomo.png",
      "webp": "./images/avatars/image-juliusomo.webp"
    },
    "username": "juliusomo"
  },
  "comments": [{
      "id": 1,
      "content": "Impressive! Though it seems the drag feature could be improved. But overall it looks incredible. You've nailed the design and the responsiveness at various breakpoints works really well.",
      "createdAt": "1 month ago",
      "score": 12,
      "user": {
        "image": {
          "png": "./images/avatars/image-amyrobson.png",
          "webp": "./images/avatars/image-amyrobson.webp"
        },
        "username": "amyrobson"
      },
      "replies": []
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "content": "Woah, your project looks awesome! How long have you been coding for? I'm still new, but think I want to dive into React as well soon. Perhaps you can give me an insight on where I can learn React? Thanks!",
      "createdAt": "2 weeks ago",
      "score": 5,
      "user": {
        "image": {
          "png": "./images/avatars/image-maxblagun.png",
          "webp": "./images/avatars/image-maxblagun.webp"
        },
        "username": "maxblagun"
      },
      "replies": [{
        "id": 3,
        "content": "If you're still new, I'd recommend focusing on the fundamentals of HTML, CSS, and JS before considering React. It's very tempting to jump ahead but lay a solid foundation first.",
        "createdAt": "1 week ago",
        "score": 4,
        "replyingTo": "maxblagun",
        "user": {
          "image": {
            "png": "./images/avatars/image-ramsesmiron.png",
            "webp": "./images/avatars/image-ramsesmiron.webp"
          },
          "username": "ramsesmiron"
        }
      }]
    }
  ]
}

console.log(data.comments[1].replies)
```